# Rats in range hood

Tags: exhaust-fan, range

I’ve just discovered I have rats in my range hood above my stove top in my kitchen. I’ve turned the fan on and heard a lot of squealing and crunches. Can clearly see the rat aswell stuck in the fan. But the noises have been going on for weeks but I just thought nothing of it. Please can someone help me? What do I do? Can they cause a fire?? I have a 4 year old aswell so I’m stuck as I have no idea what to do.

Bianca, NZ

Comment: Rats are nasty business!  My recommendation is to call an exterminator do remove the rats and then call a "restoration" company who can identify the point of entrance and close it up and then repair any damage that has been done.

Comment: Thank you. I’ve spoken with my landlord and he will follow it up tomorrow. Can rats cause an electrical fire?

Comment: If they chew on the wiring, they most certainly can. They can eat through the insulation leaving bare wires that can later arc causing a fire. Part of the remediation process should be an inspection of the wiring in the hood, the walls, and anywhere else in the they've been identified.

Comment: This is probably one of the few questions we get here where "call a pro" is likely the best answer you'll get.

Comment: Rodents are never good above your cooking surfaces. I would use caution in getting rid of them even the dead ones. A guy in southern oregon got the Black Plague trying to save a mouse from his cat. The mouse and cat died and the man lost some of his fingers if I remember correctly and almost died because the mouse was carrying the disease. I know rodents are thought to be responsible for “valley fever” further south so you really don’t want critters there to start with and have them chewing on the wiring.

Comment: First try to remove the filter (the lowest part). Then you can see more.